# Pytorch fails to load pyannote-audio model with error hubconf.py file not found

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, model, pyaudio, torchvision

I am trying to load pre-trained model for pyannote-audio for speaker change detection using below torch and pyannote-audio versions.

```
torch == 1.12.1+cu102
pyannote.audio== 1.1.2
```

I have tried with latest versions as well.

Below code is giving me the given error:

```
import torch
scd = torch.hub.load('pyannote/pyannote-audio', 'scd')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.cache/torch/hub/pyannote_pyannote-audio_main/hubconf.py'
```

How can i resolve the error to use the given pre-trained model?